# How to Increase the Performance of a `ListView.builder`?

Tags: android, performance, flutter, listview, stream

I have a `ListView.builder` That builds videos from firebase, it works fine but when I go up and down many times so it rebuilds, The Video throws an error, I think it is because listview.builder, any ideas how to prevent this ?

**Code**

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: _store
      .collection('Khatma Collection')
      .document('Khatma 1')
      .collection('Videos')
      .snapshots(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          var link = snapshot.data.documents[i].data['Link'];
          var uploader = snapshot.data.documents[i].data['Uploader'];
          var likes = snapshot.data.documents[i].data['Likes'];
          var like = likes.toString();
          bool liked;
          if (int.parse(like) > 0) {
            liked = true;
          } else if (int.parse(like) == 0) {
            liked = false;
          }
          final videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(link);
          chewieController = ChewieController(
            allowMuting: true,
            autoInitialize: true,
            deviceOrientationsAfterFullScreen: orientation,
            allowFullScreen: true,
            aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
            videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
          );
          return link != null
              ? SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Chewie(
                        controller: chewieController,
                      ),
                    ],
                  );

              ...
```

Comment: Is it because I am using snapshots ?

Comment: What kind of error. We cant help you if we dont know the error your saying.

Comment: Running in debug mode is generally slow even with just texts in a list view.

Comment: first , The video gives me a warning sign, but no error printed, second I am not running it in debug mode.